# How to Receive cypress interception fixture twice but in different format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cypress, fixtures, intercept

I'm a beginner with Cypress and I am stuggeling with the following:

I am calling the following from my test file:

```
cy.SetupClassificationsStubFixture(1);
```

This refers to the following command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("SetupClassificationsStubFixture", (amount) => {

cy.fixture('ClassificationsStub.json').then(classificationsStub => {
    const slicedClassifications = classificationsStub.slice(0, amount)
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/classifications', slicedClassifications)
}).as('classifications')


cy.fixture('ClassificationsStub.json').then(classificationsStub => {
    const slicedClassifications = classificationsStub.slice(0, amount)
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/classifications/*', slicedClassifications)
}).as('classifications') });
```

As you can see this customcommand is intercepting 2 api request. Namely:

1. ** /api/classifications
2. ** /api/classifications/ *

The first interception is with []
The second intercecption needs exactly the same response buth without brackets []

But you already understand that both respons are now with brackets '[]'. I tried to make a second fixture file without [], but the the slice function is not working.

So I need:
The second intercept like:

```
{
    "id": "9d4a9c14-ef37-4a64-a1eb-63ab45cdf530",
    "name": "CypressTest",
    "userRole": "Editor",
    "childClassifications": []
}
```

But I get:

```
[{
    "id": "9d4a9c14-ef37-4a64-a1eb-63ab45cdf530",
    "name": "CypressTest",
    "userRole": "Editor",
    "childClassifications": []
}]
```

How could I get this array back without []? Thankyou indeed!

UPDATE:
I am trying now the following:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("SetupClassificationsStubFixture", (amount) => {

cy.fixture('ClassificationsStub.json').then(classificationsStub => {
    const slicedClassifications = classificationsStub.slice(0, amount)
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/classifications', slicedClassifications)
}).as('classifications')


cy.fixture('ClassificationsStub.json').then(classificationsStub => {
    const slicedClassifications = classificationsStub.slice(0, amount)
    const arr2 = slicedClassifications
    const obj5 = Object.fromEntries(arr2)
    
   
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/classifications/*', obj5)
}).as('classification')});
```

But this give me a emtpy .json file. It the respons is not just ' {} '

Comment: What is this doing `classificationsStub.slice(0, amount)` ?

Comment: In the map Fixtures there is a file named "classificationsStub.json". In this .json file is a array with several objects.  And with .slice I am selecting the needed objects from the .json file.

.slice(0,5) means: Use the first five objects.
.slice(2,4) means: Use the 2nd, 3th and 4th objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved with:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("SetupClassificationsStubFixture", (amount) => {

cy.fixture('ClassificationsStub.json').then(classificationsStub => {
    const slicedClassifications = classificationsStub.slice(0, amount)
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/classifications', slicedClassifications)
}).as('classifications')


cy.fixture('ClassificationsStub.json').then(classificationsStub => {
   
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/classifications/*', (req) => {
        const slicedClassifications = classificationsStub.slice(0, amount)
        var selectedClassification = req.url.replace(new RegExp('.*api/classifications/'), '');
        let foundClassification = FindChildClassification(selectedClassification, slicedClassifications);

        //If not found return first always
        req.reply({
                    statusCode: 200,
            body: foundClassification ?? slicedClassifications[0]
                })
    })
}).as('classification')
```

And

```
export function FindChildClassification(id, classificationArray) {
for (let i = 0; classificationArray.length - 1 >= i; i++) {
    if (classificationArray[i].id == id) {
        return classificationArray[i];
    } else {
        if (classificationArray[i].childClassifications.length > 0) {
            let childClassification = FindChildClassification(id, classificationArray[i].childClassifications);
            if (childClassification != null) { return childClassification }
        }
    }
}

return null;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be some brackets out of place in the code.

I would also recommend using different alias names, otherwise the calls to `cy.wait('@classifications')` may not work as you expect.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("SetupClassificationsStubFixture", (amount) => {

  cy.fixture('ClassificationsStub.json').then(classificationsStub => {

    const slicedClassifications = classificationsStub.slice(0, amount)
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/classifications', slicedClassifications)
      .as('classifications')

    const firstClassification = slicedClassifications[0]  // just first item
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/classifications/*', firstClassification)
      .as('firstClassification') 

  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have implemented them. Do you also have the trick to convert the array in to an object (without [] brackets ?)

I see a potential solution with object.entries . Should this work?

Comment: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-convert-array-to-object#convert-an-array-to-object-using-objectfromentries

Comment: The way I do above is `const firstClassification = slicedClassifications[0]` - that "takes the brackets off" - not really a technical way of describing it :).

Comment: So you can also do `const firstClassification = classificationsStub[0]`, it ends up with the same value you want for the 2nd `cy.intercept()`.

Answer (score 0):

So in case, your data looks like this:

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "9d4a9c14-ef37-4a64-a1eb-63ab45cdf530",
    "name": "CypressTest",
    "userRole": "Editor",
    "childClassifications": []
}]
```

So to extract the data with just curly braces you can do `data[0]`.

```js
{
    "id": "9d4a9c14-ef37-4a64-a1eb-63ab45cdf530",
    "name": "CypressTest",
    "userRole": "Editor",
    "childClassifications": []
}
```

Working example console screenshot:

[image: console sccreenshot]

Comment: Can you add a specific example of how OP would use this in their test suite? You've just outlined a general strategy, and if OP doesn't understand the difference between Objects and Arrays, your answer might now make sense.

Comment: For that I have already asked OP a follow up question.

Comment: Actually This solution would not work for me. Because in the ficture map there is a file classificationsStub.json. 
This file is contains an array with objects inside. And the .slice function is only working with arrays. 
So at the end I still need to use the .slice but I need the output without []. 

So Maybe there is a way to wrap / convert the array in to a object? In otherword: I need a output from an array. An array starts and ends with [ ]. But I need this without []